# Custom sum formula

Tags: excel, math, formula

How can I write a formula to add the numbers from column C, whereby the sum should be written in columns D-L (and I should add only those numbers that are in the row with the letter R)? The screenshot will explain what I mean.

[image]

Comment: Did you try `SUMIFS` yet?

Comment: @BigBen No, I didn't, I would be very grateful for the formula example.

Comment: Try your favorite search engine?

Comment: @BigBen Classic StackOverflow response :) I didn't know what to google it because I didn't even know how to phrase the question without the help of a screenshot. I'll google SUMIFS. You can submit SUMIFS as an answer if you think it should help, I'll test and accept it.

Comment: Honestly, I've voted to close. `SUMIFS` is a very basic Excel formula, and does not really merit an answer.

Comment: @BigBen I very rarely work with excel, for me, this is a discovery and it really helped me! Maybe this will help someone else too. So if you change your mind, I'll accept your answer, thank you.